# How to change UI components color when some other Thread is running?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I got some game to build (yes it's an assignment from university) which I need to go over some matrix that represents a board with two states (boolean[][]). This board can be seen as a GUI that build using JLabels in two colors.

The idea is to have some background process which go each cell to have some update on the matrix by certain rules. By these rules I need to change the matrix cell value in the UI side.

Currently I made a seperate Thread for the process which goes over the matrix and checks the rule I got, and another Thread which is responsible for making the change in the UI.

By that, the first Thread is working well while the second does nothing.

So my question is, what is the best way to change Swing UI while some other process is working in the background?

What I done so far is this:

```
this.golThread = new Thread(golr);
golr.setRunningMode(true);
golThread.start();

this.uiThread = new Thread(ui);
ui.setRunningMode(true);
uiThread.start();
```

And I also tried to use: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(uiThread);`

Comment: `invokeLater` is the correct way, if that didn't work then you have some other problem.

Comment: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) would be a start. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @markspace, how can I update only one JLabel from my second Thread without creating it all over again ?

Comment: How are you managing the labels?  Are they in some kind of array or `List`?  You can't change what you don't have a reference to